# Multiple Configurations of a Bean with Spring Annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations

In my example here, I have a "Hero" bean which can be injected with a "Weapon" bean. Both Heros and Weapons are prototype-scoped (we can have multiple heroes, and they won't share weapons).

What I want to have is a Hero configuration called "Warrior" which is injected with a "Sword" weapon, and a Hero configuration called "Archer" which is injected with a "Bow" weapon. Then in my application I would call

```
context.getBean("Warrior");
```

each time I want to get a new warrior.

I know how to do this with XML, but I was wondering if it is possible to do this with annotations? If so, how do I do it? I am using Spring 4.

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but seems that you can autowire the setter in the subclass to the specify the specific kind of `Weapon` your `Hero` will use.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That would work if I only had one type of Hero, but how do you link the type of weapon to the type of hero?

Comment: You can use [Qualifiers](http://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.0.6.RELEASE/index.html?org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html)

Comment: My comment goes to define the `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier` in the setter of the subclass, for your case, in `Warrior` and `Archer` classes, while in `Hero` class you only define `Weapon`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example of LuiggiMendoza's comment (autowiring and qualifying the setter)

Sticking to the script of programming to interfaces, we have the `Hero` interface

```
public interface Hero {
    void killOrBeKilled();
}
```

We'll also have an `AbstractHero` abstract class to put together some common functionality. Notice we don't implement the `setWeapon` method. We'll leave that to the concrete class.

```
public abstract class AbstractHero implements Hero {
    protected Weapon weapon;

    public void killOrBeKilled() {
        weapon.secretWeaponManeuver();
    }

    protected abstract void setWeapon(Weapon weapon);
}
```

And here are the [Qualifiers](http://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.0.6.RELEASE/index.html?org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) we'll use. Note, you don't *have* to create your own qualifiers. You could simply use `@Qualifer("qualifierName")` for your matchings. I did it just because I *could* :P

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface BowType { }

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface SwordType { }
```

For the `Warrior` we'll use the `@SwordType` qualifier

```
@Component  
public class Warrior extends AbstractHero {
    @SwordType
    @Autowired
    public void setWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }
}
```

And for the `Archer` we'll use the `@BowType` qualifier

```
@Component
public class Archer extends AbstractHero {
    @BowType
    @Autowired
    public void setWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
        this.weapon = weapon;   
    }
}
```

In our `Weapons` concrete classes, we'll also need to annotate the classes with the appropriate qualifiers

```
public interface Weapon {
    void secretWeaponManeuver();
}

@BowType    
@Component
public class Bow implements Weapon {
    public void secretWeaponManeuver() {
        System.out.println("Bow goes Slinnnggggg!");    
    }
}

@SwordType
@Component
public class Sword implements Weapon {
    public void secretWeaponManeuver() {
        System.out.println("Sword goes Slassshhhh!");   
    }
}
```

When we run the application, the weapon types will be injected properly based on our qualifiers

```
@Configuration  
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.stackoverflow.spring.hero"})
public class Config { }

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractApplicationContext context = 
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

        Hero warrior = context.getBean(Warrior.class);
        warrior.killOrBeKilled();

        Hero archer = context.getBean(Archer.class);
        archer.killOrBeKilled();

        context.close();
    }
}
```

Result

> Sword goes Slassshhhh!
>   Bow goes Slinnnggggg!

P.S. I forgot the `@Scope("prototype")` annotation.

- See [Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) for more info on using qualifiers

Comment: Fantastic example. What I was trying to avoid was creating Warrior and Archer subclasses, but I think this is close enough.